# OpenLayers 5 forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent Method Not Correctly Selecting Features in Circle or Polygon?

Tags: openlayers, features, extents

Using OpenLayers 5.3.3

1. Draw a circle
2. Get the extent of the circle in the `drawend` event:
     `const extent = event.feature.getGeometry().getExtent();`
3. The try to determine the features in the extent using `forEachFeatureInExtent`
4. The collection of features returned include features that are outside the boundaries of the circle.

The same behavior occurs for an irregularly shaped polygon. However, for a drawn box it appears to work correctly.

Why is the `forEachFeatureInExtent` not correctly returning the features in the specified extent? What has to be done differently for a circle or irregularly shaped polygon?

Comment: Definition of geometry extent could be stated also as: _The smallest **rectangle** aligned with coordinate axes that contains the whole geometry_. This explains behavior you are getting. I don't have a lot of experience with OpenLayers, but as far as I know, there is no built in method for checking if one geometry contains the other one. For this you can for example use Turf.js library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a box would not work correctly if the view was rotated (see the box selection example which has been updated for version 6 https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/box-selection.html)

If you are attempting to select Point features with a circle you could consider the initial result a shortlist and check each for intersection with the circle geometry:

```
const circle = event.feature.getGeometry();
const selected = [];
source.forEachFeatureInExtent(circle.getExtent(), function(feature) {
  if (circle.intersectsExtent(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()) {
    selected.push(feature);
  }
});
```

Comment: According to the OpenLayers docs feature.getExtent() is not a method. Do you mean feature.getGeometry().getExtent() instead?

Comment: Yes, it must be accessed via the geometry

Comment: So this works for points but not for testing if a polygon is w/in a polygon/circle. Comparing the extent of a polygon provides a rectangular representation which does not accurately reflect the borders of the polygon. Would one have to compare all the coordinates of the polygon to determine if they are in the circle/polygon?

Comment: OpenLayers doesn't have a method to test if geometries intersect unless one of them is a point.  Edges might intersect a circle even if the vertices don't so you would need to use a third party tool such as turf.

Comment: Any insights as to what methods in Turf would be applicable to this problem? I'm a relative newcomer to the geospatial area.

Comment: You would need the `intersect` method https://turfjs.org/docs/#intersect  A non-null result means the polygons intersect.  Note that turf uses GeoJSON feature objects so you must convert from OpenLayers features using `writeFeatureObject` as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/turf.html and turf doesn't support Circle geometry so OpenLayers must create an equivalent Polygon using `ol/geom/Polygon.fromCircle` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_Polygon.html

Comment: Thanks Mike for the details.